# Using Fragments and TabListener the right way

Tags: android, android-fragments

My problem is about fragments with tabs. I have got one activity which basically has an empty layout and I add fragments to it dynamically. As soon as I start the activity I add a fragment with a listview to it and when I click on an item of the list I remove the fragment with the listview and add another fragment with details about it. Also some tabs are visible now. Clicking on one of these tabs shows other details about the item from the listview.

I do have working code but it seems that I'm hacking it altogether.

Here is some bits of it:

### Activity:

```
// In onCreate:
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
      // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
      // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
      // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
      }
      // Create an instance of FList
      fList = new FList();
      // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fList).commit();
    }
  }



// After clicking on an item of the listview changeFragment() is called
public void changeFragment() {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fSpeed = new FSpeed();
  ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fSpeed);

  // this might be necessary
  if (actionBar != null)
    actionBar.selectTab(tabSpeed);
  ft.commit();
}

// In the activity I also setup the ActionBar with tabs
private void setupActionBar() {
  tabSpeed = actionBar.newTab();
  // and a few more tabs...
  tabSpeed.setTabListener(this);
  actionBar.addTab(tabSpeed);
  // But the tabs are not visible because of the navigation mode
  actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
}

// Here is the tabListener - very hacky!
@Override
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    if (fm == null)
      fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment f = null;
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
      if (fSpeed == null)
        fSpeed = new FSpeed();
      f = findFragment(fSpeed);
      if (f != null) {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_alpha_0_1, R.anim.fragment_alpha_1_0);
        ft.remove(f);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fSpeed);
      } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "fSpeed is " + f);
        return;
      }
      break;
      case 1:
        // more tabs - similar code
    }

// the findFragment() method
private Fragment findFragment(Fragment selectedFragment) {
  if (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) == fSpeed && selectedFragment != fSpeed)
    return fSpeed;
  // more ifs for other fragments
  else
    return null;
}
```

This all worked fine for the minute but after switching x times between the tabs things started looking funny, e.g. fList was visible, tab icons disappeared, ... I could track the bugs down and add some null checks but I think I went the wrong way. This is why I changed the TabListener with the following one:

```
// Still in activity
public static class MyTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements TabListener {
  private Fragment mFragment;
  private final Activity mActivity;
  private final String mTag;
  private final Class<T> mClass;
  /**
  * * Constructor used each time a new tab is created. 
  * * * @param
  * activity * The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment 
  * * @param
  * tag * The identifier tag for the fragment 
  * * @param clz * The
  * fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
  */
  public MyTabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mTag = tag;
    mClass = clz;
    }

  /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFragment == null) {
      // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
      mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
      ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
    // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
      ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
  }

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  if (mFragment != null) {
    ft.detach(mFragment);
  }
}

// The tabs are now assigned to MyTabListener
tabSpeed.setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FSpeed>(this, "speed", FSpeed.class));
```

Here is where the problem started. After clicking on an item from the listview with the new TabListener onTabSelected and onTabUnSelected are called in turns endlessly.

### Question:

My question is how do you go from a fragment with a listview to another fragment after clicking on an item of the listview (and still use the same activity). Is my own written method changeFragment() the wrong approach? Still I would like to use the MyTabListener.

*Note 1: I bought Commonsware's book to learn more about fragments but I couldn't find a more complex example with different fragments working together and also couldn't find how the back button is handled, or overridden. For example after clicking on the back button if fragment1, 2 or 3 are visible always show fragment4. If anybody found one in the book could you please tell me the chapter (name)/ page? If there isn't it would be very kind of the Common guys to provide one in the next update or so.*

*Note 2: Global variables were used in the project like fSpeed, tabSpeed, ...*

*Note 3: If you need more code or explanation please let me know in the comments. Thanks for helping!*

Answer (score 0):

> Is my own written method changeFragment() the wrong approach?

You are adding a fragment, not replacing one. To replace a fragment, use `replace()`, not `add()`.